# Secure folder contents and delete them after certain number of days

Tags: windows, powershell, security, directory

I would like to secure folder, so that no one can cut or copy any file or contents of file without "secure" password (or happy to get rid of password bit as well, so no one can cut, copy or move any file or file contents from folder). Also, if all files and folders inside my root folder can be deleted after certain number of days, that will be great. This is to stop people from copying and distributing my files to others without my permission and folder contents to "expire" after certain number of days (e.g. 7 days).

Currently, I manually copy folder to other people's machine, so I do have physical access to their machines.

PS. I am happy to write a script as well, in case there is a way to execute script everytime I open the folder.

I understand, I can't stop people from stealing file contents by manually typing file contents to other file or taking photos of file contents, however I want to make it harder of them.

Comment: Do people need access to these documents, cant you just stop sharing it?

Comment: yes. They are students and need read only access to all the notes and assignments. However, they are distributing those notes and assignments to their friends and thus causing loss to our business!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a PowerShell issue, nor a solution provided by PowerShell. This is an data risk management issue as well as a reality check.

Don't get me wrong, you can write a scrip that encrypts data,

```
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/06/powertip-encrypt-files-with-powershell
```

Even just use EFS, but each of those have several limitations.

```
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116.aspx
```

Then there are password encrypted zip files. But.....

None of the above stop cut/copy/paste/print and there is no way to make them.

Here is the simple truth to data security which I deliver at all my public speaking engagements and customer deployment engagements.

Nothing can defeat and ocular attack. Meaning...

```
'If I can see your data, I can take your data.'
```

It may take me longer than being able to just bulk exfiltrate you data (copy to a USB, CD, DVD, native print, etc), but I can just take a picture, photo copy it, screen grab it from another device, manually write it down.

Either method allows me to walk away with it and give it to whomever.

You can only mitigate / slow down / prevent bulk exfiltration using DLP/RMS protection solutions.

Why are you putting this manually on their systems, vs hosting it in the cloud where they can access it. If you do this in MS Azure, you can leverage Azure Information Protection.

> RMS for individuals and Azure Information Protection
>
> RMS for individuals is a free self-service subscription for users in
>   an organization who need to open files that have been protected by the
>   Azure Rights Management service from Azure Information Protection. If
>   these users cannot be authenticated by Azure Active Directory and
>   their organization does not have Active Directory Rights Management
>   (AD RMS), this free sign-up service can create an account in Azure
>   Active Directory for a user. As a result, these users can now
>   authenticate by using their company email address and then read the
>   protected files on computers or mobile devices.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/understand-explore/rms-for-individuals

Why are you not heavily watermarking your data?

Putting passwords on files and folders do not prevent that ocular attack.
Neither does DLP/RMS. You can apply cut/copy/paste/print policies, remove access after a certain date, restrict access as per the feature set using policies.

Yet, again, this is just prevention against the bulk dumping / sharing of your data. Not the fine grained, patient, write it down or capture from a remote camera approach. Even if you block cut / copy / paste from the host, I can bring that host up is a screen sharing - think remote desktop, and screen shoot in the RDP session. Meaning, using the host tools that I use to connect to an RDP destination. Heck I create a webcast and share it with a group, meaning, I open it on my system and let people view it with me.

No DLP solution is 100%. Anyone telling you this is lying.

As one that has been doing Info/CyberSec for almost 2 decades, evaluated, deployed and used several DLP solutions, what I state here is from experience. DLP is important, and business must look to it as another mitigation in their risk strategies, but must do so with real vision and reality.

No matter who it is from, no technology can prevent this ocular avenue. If you don't want your data leaving your control, then don't share it. Yet, since you are in the education business, that is not an option.

I'll say it again, and again...

```
'If I can see your data, I can take your data.'
```